# Invalid argument in sendto

Tags: c, sockets, struct

I have two programs which communicate with each other.

Client: First send the message then listen for reply.
Server: Listen for reply and then send message.

Im able to send message from client prefectly and listen in server too. But problem comes when I try to send message from server.

```
struct hostent *gethostbyname();
typedef struct Message {
    unsigned int length;
    unsigned char data[SIZE];
} Message;

typedef struct sockaddr_in SocketAddress;
int fileDesc;
int aLength;

void main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Message callMsg, rep;
    aLength = 0;

    SocketAddress clientSAMain, serverSAMain;

    int port = RECIPIENT_PORT;

    if ((fileDesc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("socket failed");
        //return BAD;
    }
    makeReceiverSA(&serverSAMain, port);

    if (bind(fileDesc, (struct sockaddr *) &serverSAMain,
            sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) != 0) {
        perror("Bind failed\n");
        close(fileDesc);
        //return BAD;
    }

    clientSAMain.sin_family = AF_INET;
    aLength = sizeof(serverSAMain);
    GetRequest(&callMsg, port, &clientSAMain);

    SendReply(&rep, port, clientSAMain);
    close(fileDesc);

}

void GetRequest(Message *callMessage, int s, SocketAddress *clientSA) {
    //SocketAddress serverSA;

    int n;
    int i;

    if ((n = recvfrom(fileDesc, callMessage->data, SIZE, 0,
            (struct sockaddr *) &clientSA, &aLength)) < 0)
        perror("Receive 1");
    else

        printf("\n Received Message:(%s)length = %d \n", callMessage->data, n);

}

}


void SendReply(Message *replyMessage, int s, SocketAddress clientSANew) {

printf("Enter a reply:");
scanf("%s", replyMessage->data);

if ((n = sendto(fileDesc, replyMessage->data, sizeof(replyMessage->data), 0,
        (struct sockaddr *) &clientSANew, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))) < 0)
    perror("Send Failed in Server\n");

if (n != strlen(replyMessage->data))
    printf("sent %d\n", n + 1);

}

/* make a socket address using any of the addressses of this computer
 for a local socket on given port */
void makeReceiverSA(struct sockaddr_in *sa, int port) {
sa->sin_family = AF_INET;
sa->sin_port = htons(port);
sa->sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
}
```

//If i place the sendreply function code in GetRequest function it is working fine. Can anyone help me with this. I have been trying all the possible way but did not find a solution. Work under progress for me so spare me if it is silly question.

PS:Edited out all the unnecessary code.

Comment: Do you get a compilation error ? What is the problem ?

Comment: Sorry about the error not mentioned in the text. I have mentioned it in the title.

Comment: From manual page :
`recvfrom(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags,
                 struct sockaddr *src_addr, socklen_t *addrlen);`
takes a pointer not address of a pointer why are you doing so in GetRequest ?

`recvfrom(fileDesc, callMessage->data, SIZE, 0,
            (struct sockaddr *) &clientSA, &aLength))` `clientSA` is a pointer in the function argument
Does the getRequest function work ?

Comment: Sorry about that and thanks for pointing it out. This is what happens if I code at 3 a.m :(

Comment: So your title should read 'invalid argument in recvfrom()'?

Comment: Some how I was getting error in sendto()   ...Eventually got to know after posting this question that the problem was in recvfrom().

Answer (score 1):

```
recvfrom(fileDesc, callMessage->data, SIZE, 0,
         (struct sockaddr *) &clientSA, &aLength)
```

Because `clientSA` is a pointer, the above will overwrite the pointer variable and the memory after it.  `&clientSA` in the above call should be `clientSA`.

Comment: thank you will try this :) ...some how i missed it :(